# 'GoogleSignIn/GIDSignIn.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, 3d, google-play-games

-------------------use version---------------------------

Unity       5.5.0f3

Xcode       8.2.1

cocoapods   1.2.0

current-build/GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.36.unitypackage

---

I Added GooglePlayGamesPlugin to Unity project.

However, an error was found.

I have not been able to solve the problem for two weeks...

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALFVU.jpg)

Comment: Visit this link to get the best solution to resolve this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70984618/10635425

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow [this comment](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/issues/102#issuecomment-522417469): change it in your Podfile directly:

"`pod 'GoogleSignIn', '>= 4.0.2'`" to "`pod 'GoogleSignIn', '< 5.0.0'`"

**OR**

you change it in the `GoogleSignInDependencies.xml` (for future rebuilds of the XCode project):

File: /Assets/GoogleSignIn/Editor/GoogleSignInDependencies.xml

```
"`<iosPod name="GoogleSignIn" version=">=4.0.2" ...>`" to
"`<iosPod name="GoogleSignIn" version="< 5.0.0" ...>`"


If '<' symbol becomes red, then change it to '&lt;'
```

2. Add Cocoapods to the Xcode workspace from iOS Resolver Settings
3. Make XCode build from Unity by selecting Xcode Workspace
4. Open `.xcworkspace`, not `.xcodeproj`
5. Add `-ObjC` as Other Linker Flags in target's build settings
6. Select Pods project, then select "`GoogleUtilities`" from left side under `TARGETS`, then select "`Build Phases`" tab and add "`GoogleSignIn.framework`" and "`GoogleSignIn.bundle`" under "`Link Binary With Libraries`" by clicking + sign

***NOTE on point 6:*** As Unity adds the GoogleSignIn framework and bundle in Pods, but it couldn't able to add it's reference, so we have to do it explicitly. Remember these files are in your Pods folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been raised on a [Github post](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1009) and the provided solution was as follows:

This could be that the postprocessing of the pbxproject file did not complete successfully. You can check the Unity console log for this.

Make sure you are:

1. opening the .xcworkspace file.
2. OTHER_LDFLAGS in build settings include $(inherited)
3. HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in build settings include $(inherited)
4. OTHER_CFLAGS in build settings include $(inherited)
5. ENABLE_BITCODE in build settings is set to NO
6. Libraries/Plugins/iOS/GPGSAppController.mm (or Libraries/GPGSAppController.mm) has compiler flags that include -fobjc-arc

Answer (score 0):

This error only for missing iOS GoogleSignIn.framework.

So, download the latest framework version from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/).

Extract the zip file. there this two files drag and drop in your xcode project's Frameworks folder. Then project clean and build.

1. GoogleSignIn.framwork
2. GoogleSignInDependencies.framework